# Elasticsearch : Root mapping definition has unsupported parameter

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

I am creating a way to search for words in Thai by Elasticsearch and Kibana. I have a problem with mapping.

```
PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "trigrams": {
          "tokenizer": "trigram_tokenizer",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "trigram_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_ngram": 3,
          "max_ngram": 3,
          "token_chars": []
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "true_name": {
      "properties": {
        "correct": { "type": "text", "analyzer": "trigrams" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and error like this

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [true_name : {properties={correct={analyzer=trigrams, type=text}}}]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [true_name : {properties={correct={analyzer=trigrams, type=text}}}]",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason" : "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [true_name : {properties={correct={analyzer=trigrams, type=text}}}]"
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mapping types are deprecated. Refer to this [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html) to know more about the removal of mapping types.

> Indices created in Elasticsearch 6.0.0 or later may only contain a
> single mapping type. Indices created in 5.x with multiple mapping
> types will continue to function as before in Elasticsearch 6.x. Types
> will be deprecated in APIs in Elasticsearch 7.0.0, and completely
> removed in 8.0.0.

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "trigrams": {
          "tokenizer": "trigram_tokenizer",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "trigram_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_ngram": 3,
          "max_ngram": 3,
          "token_chars": []
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {            // note this
    "properties": {
      "correct": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "trigrams"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**If your JSON document is like this:**

```
{
  "true_name": {
    "correct": "mapping types deprecated"
  }
}
```

Then index mapping will be -

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "trigrams": {
          "tokenizer": "trigram_tokenizer",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "trigram_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_ngram": 3,
          "max_ngram": 3,
          "token_chars": []
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {              // note this
      "true_name": {
        "properties": {
          "correct": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "trigrams"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```